Identify this movie please: probably 1980's
I am looking to find a title of a movie I have seen long time ago. I think it was from the late eighties or very early nineties.
The things I remember:
-Story about a couple of employees, cheating on their boss by stealing money through (very old) computers. I believe old IBM's. And I think they stole one or two cents by every transaction. 
-The boss finds out and want to find out who they are. 
-He tell's them to find employees who suddenly turn up rich
-I think in the same scene, one of the employees drive into the parkingarea in a red Ferrari (328 or 308 I believe). But drives rather poorly.
-I thought it had Richard Pryor in it, but I can't find the movie in his filmography.

Awesome! thanks, I would never guessed that one. I've seen that title in his filmography, but never linked it to the movie I was looking for.

If this is supposed to be a response to EdChum's answer and it is the correct solution to your problem, then you might want to consider accepting his answer to mark the question as solved.

Superman 3:



Richard Pryor and Christopher Reeve (1983).
IMDB
Basically he gets recruited to hack a satellite to control the weather and harm the coffee crops I seem to remember, he's then asked to divert all oil tankers to the middle of the atlantic ocean to bump up the oil price and is then asked to find the chemical formula for Kryptonite but has to substitute nicotine for the unknown compound. He also designs a super computer that can do 'anything'.
The hacking scene can be found here: 



This plot (stealing the "half-cents" from interest transactions), and Superman III specifically, was referenced in the movie Office Space, when the 3 main male characters do the same thing.
